# splice array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, splice

I have array of arrays:

```
Array
(
   [0] => "title"
   [1] => Array
         (
             [0] => a
             [1] => b
             [2] => c
         )
   [2] => Array
         (
             [0] => d
             [1] => e
             [2] => f
         )
)
```

I need to insert an array into first array like the following

```
Array
(
   [0] => "title"
   [1] => Array
         (
             [0] => a
             [1] => b
             [2] => c
         )
   [2] => Array
         (
             [0] => a1
             [1] => b1
             [2] => c1
         )
   [3] => Array
         (
             [0] => d
             [1] => e
             [2] => f
         )
)
```

I don't know how to use `array_splice()`. I tried it this way but it didn't work.

```
array_splice($main_array, 2, 0 $array_to_insert)
```

Comment: This is PHP, not JavaScript.

Comment: Did you do anything with the return value of `array_splice`?

Comment: I think he talks about arrayName.splice, not the array_splice. So is js.

Comment: Yes, $arr = array_splice(.....);

Comment: You are right zozo, seems I messed up something. I talk about array.splice() (javascript not php).

Comment: Then both Amrendra's and my solutions are good (are actually the same), despite the fact that some nice people minused mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$main_array = array(0 => "title",1 => array("a","b"));

$array_to_insert = array("c","d");

$new_array = array_splice($main_array, 1, 0, array($array_to_insert));

print_r($main_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: After reading the comments it seems this is a javascript question. :) ??!!.. Just for completeness, this is a PHP solution - as requested ;)

---

`array_splice()` is the correct approach. Use the following code:

```
<?php

$arr = array (
 'title',
 array('a', 'b', 'c'),
 array('d', 'e', 'f')
);
var_dump($arr);

// note that I've wrapped the array to be inserted into another, empty, array
array_splice($arr, 2, 0, array(array('a1', 'b1', 'c1')));

// further note that array_splice will not return the new array. $arr is
// passed by reference and will get modified from inside of array_splice
var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you...

```
    var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
a.splice(2,0,'a','b');  // Returns []; a is [1,2,'a','b',3,4,5]
a.splice(2,2,[1,2],3);  // Returns ['a','b']; a is [1,2,[1,2],3,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check Following code

```
 $array_to_insert = array(0  => array( 0 => 'a1',1 => 'b1',2 => 'c1'));
   // You need to have nexted array

    $main_array = array(0 => "title",1 => array(0 => a,1 => b,2 => c),2 => array(0 => d,1 => 
e,2 => f));

    array_splice($main_array, 2, 0, $array_to_insert); 

    var_dump($main_array);
```

Answer (score -1):

nameOfArray[3] = ["d", "e", "f"]. Also splice is ok, but it must be used like: array.splice(index, howMany, whatToInsert)

Comment: actually ['d', 'e', 'f'] already exist in my array. I need to insert ['a1', 'b1', 'c1] before it.